# Ember.Select cannot observe change to selection variable of dynamically generated control

Tags: ember.js

I am dynamically building a number of select controls.  I want to know when an option has changed so I am doing the following:

The idea there is that I dynamically create properties on the `selections` object which is used to hold the selected values.

```
//Add observer
Ember.defineProperty(selections, camelizedModelClass, null);
selections.addObserver(camelizedModelClass, self, 'selectionChanged');
```

Here is the function that should be called when selection has changed.

```
selectionChanged : function(sender, key, value, rev) {
    console.log('worked!');
},
```

In my template I create Ember.Select's as follows.

```
{{#each control in controls}}

        <div {{bind-attr class=":form-group control.width"}}>
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">{{control.label}}</label>
            {{view "select"
            content=control.content
            selection=control.selection
            optionValuePath=control.optionValuePath
            optionLabelPath=control.optionLabelPath
            class = "form-control"
            prompt=control.prompt
            }}
            <p class="help-block"></p>
        </div>

{{/each}}
```

Each control in the  `controls` array has the following property.

```
selection: 'selections.' + camelizedModelClass,
```

The observer method is never called, however, if I manually enter the selection as follows it is in fact called.

```
{{view "select"
content=control.content
selection=selections.manager   <-------- manually specifying the selection
optionValuePath=control.optionValuePath
optionLabelPath=control.optionLabelPath
class = "form-control"
prompt=control.prompt
}}
```

Why is this not working?  The other weird thing is that if I put `{{control.selection}}` in my handlebars template I can see the model changing for the first method but not the second.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Ember.SelectView `selection` property to `value`.

```
{{view 'select' value=selections.manager}}
```

Here is an example.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/boluba/1/edit

Comment: apart of now only selecting the `id` instead of the DS.Model, I still have the same issue.

Comment: the value will be set to what is defined by the `optionValuePath`

Comment: But the `selectionChanged` function is still not being fired, that is the issue I am having.

Comment: It is either you are not observing the correct property or not setting it. In your example you were not defining the `value` property. Nothing gets set on select when using the `selection` property.

Comment: make a jsbin example.

Comment: ok will do, the code is kind of complex though, will take a while.